# Selecting a random word from an array in python

Tags: python

Is there a way for me to create an array of words then pick a random word from that array then state the first letter of that random word from said array in python?

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import choice

choice(your_list)
```

example:

```
from random import choice

my_list = ["apples", "oranges", "pears"]
print(choice(my_list)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can randint to get a random index for the list

```
your_list = ['Hello','world']
from random import randint
print(your_list[randint(0,len(your_list)-1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope this helps.

```
words = ['Random', 'Words', 'hello'] #Creating a list
from random import choice # importing choice 
random_letter = choice(words)[0] #getting the random word and then getting the first letter by indexing
print(random_letter)# printing output
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# Import the random module
import random 

# Choose a random word from your list
randomWord = random.choice(your_list)

# Print that random word but only the first letter, which is done by adding the [0] at the end. 
print(randomWord[0])
```

Comment: That won't work... it need to be `print(randomWord)`

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: @reznik, this does work. @ pppery, I added some clarification, thanks for the recommendation.